# Maximal unramified intermediate extension of DVRs

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $A\rightarrow B$ be a finite tamely ramified extension of discrete valuation rings.

Does there exist a DVR $C$ such that $A\subseteq C\subseteq B$ with $C$ unramified over $A$ and $B$ totally ramified over $C$?